# How can I plot $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, graphing-functions

I want to plot $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$?
I can plot functions of a single variable but I don't know how to plot multivariable function.

Comment: This is obviously hard to do on paper because you need $3$ dimensions.

Comment: Imagine you slice your surface by planes parallel to plane $XY$. For any particular $z_0$, $x^2+y^2=z_0$ is the equation of the cross section. If we slice it by planes parallel to plane $XZ$, we have $z=x^2+y_0$ is the equation of the cross section and so forth.

Comment: Use level surfaces to get what $f$ looks like at set values. For example, what does $x^2+y^2=1$ look like? What about $x^2+y^2=10$? What if you convert this function to cylindrical coordinates? That looks like a parabola, but in what plane?

Answer (score 0):

Your plot has three dimensions.  You can plot it in perspective, in contour lines, or in various other representations.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot3d%20x%5E2%2By%5E2) gives the following:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The graph of this function will be a surface in space. Above the point $(x,y)$ in the plane it has height $f(x,y)$.

[image]
https://www.mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/paraboloidrevolution/paraboloidrevolution.shtml

Answer (score 0):

In order to sketch this surface we need to consider
$$z=x^2+y^2=(\text{distance of }(x,y)\text{ from }(0,0))^2$$
So this is intuitively equivalent to the surface created by rotating the graph of $z=x^2$ about the $z$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ we clearly need to visualise it in $\mathbb{R^{2+1}}$,and since the domain is $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ the graph will be a surface!!
If you want to visualise any such fuction you can use https://www.wolframalpha.com/ and your graph looks like https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2By%5E2

PS:I would suggest you to use LaTeX to type your questions.